# How to document functions that are enabled with SFINAE with Doxygen?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

In a library I'm developing, I often have this kind of code:

```
template<typename T = P, enable_if_c<has_V_field<T>> = detail::dummy>
constexpr std::size_t v(){
    return T::V;
}

template<typename T = P, disable_if_c<has_V_field<T>> = detail::dummy>
constexpr std::size_t v(){
    return 1;
}
```

The two functions do the same thing, but are enabled based on the type. I'd like to document only one of then and moreover, I would like if possible to show it in Doxygen without the template stuff, as `constexpr std::size_t v()`. For the user, the templates here have not value at all.

Is that kind of thing possible with Doxygen ?

Answer (score 5):

You can put the function you'd like to see in a conditional section like so:

```
#ifdef DOXYGEN_ONLY

/*! documentation for v. */
constexpr std::size_t v();

#else // actual implementation with two variants selected via SFINAE

template<typename T = P, enable_if_c<has_V_field<T>> = detail::dummy>
constexpr std::size_t v(){
    return T::V;
}

template<typename T = P, disable_if_c<has_V_field<T>> = detail::dummy>
constexpr std::size_t v(){
    return 1;
}

#endif
```

and then use the following configuration settings:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
PREDEFINED             = DOXYGEN_ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `\fn`: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfn

Something like: (untested)

```
/*! \fn template<typename T> constexpr std::size_t v()
 *  \brief A function.
 *  \return 1 or T::V.
 */
```

Comment: I tried it and it simply documents one of v() functions and if I put it with another name it does not do anything :(